# C# LINQ-to-SQL - not updating table with stored procedure

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, linq-to-sql, datacontext, insert-update

SOLVED

I have problems with *Linq to SQL* inserting/updating/deleting dataset from table with stored procedures.

1. I have checked data connections, points on the same table that has been created when adding connection
2. I'm using *Linq-to-Sql* classes designer for managing behavior of sprocs for my tables  (insert, update, delete)
3. I have same app created with different code style and everything works just fine but i can't include location change (when someone else installs app) in my .cs files, so I want to do it on "right way" and make it work for everyone.
4. using sql server 2012 and vs2010

Here is my problem.
this is included in form as reference for *DataContext*

```
private ZavrsniradDataContext poziv = new ZavrsniradDataContext();
//I've tried without private, and including this into methods where I'm  using it and nothing.
```

after I declare some variables for sending it to sproc I call sproc for altering the table..

```
poziv.p_IzmjenaMjesta(@ID, @Naziv, @PP, @IDZupanije);
poziv.SubmitChanges();
```

note: I'm sending ID number of the dataset I want to change, for comparison..

```
Alter proc [dbo].[p_IzmjenaMjesta]
@ID int,
@Naziv varchar(30),
@PP int,
@IDZupanije int
.
.
.
Update Mjesto 
SET Naziv= @Naziv, PostanskiPretinac = @PP, IDZupanije = @IDZupanije
WHERE ID = @ID;
```

After I call the sproc, my table is being refreshed, and all changes are visible. But after a while, all changes dissapear. I believe all my sprocs and functions are working properly, with my table, but somehow I'm doing something wrong. everything works perfecrly when I run sprocs in Management studio.

My other app contains this definition in beggining of the form, and everything works perfectly. updateing, inserting, deleting!  But i don't want that solution because then I have to create fixed location for my database on every PC. I just want to install it and run it :)

```
public partial class Mjesta : Form
{
    ZavrsniRad poziv;

    public Mjesta()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        poziv = new ZavrsniRad(@"c:\zavrsni_rad\Zavrsni rad.mdf");
    }
```

NOTE:
I'm using exact copy of both databases on different locations with same sprocs/functions/dataset for different apps, and one is working, the other one is not working.
and that grinds my gears :(

Comment: Are you using transactions?  Is it possible that a transaction isn't getting committed?

Comment: yes, I'm using transactions in stored procedure (not in vs). it is possible, but i don't understand why, because on other app everything works.

Comment: Is the database that get's cleared part of the solution? Just a guess, but a (re)build of the project might overwrite it with a fresh one.

Comment: I'm sorry but i don't understand what are you asking me :/
if you mean is this DB that is rejecting my updates/inserts part of the project, then yes. it's also added as data connection, and I created linqtosql class dbml file from that DB.
when i export solution to .exe file and instal it, app won't do any changes, i can just use datasets that have been inserted prior to connecting in to project/solution..

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it.
app is running and working properly...
I forgot on that little thing :(

Problem solver, add all rights on modifying your database to every account you have.
That also includes rights to log file.

(i dont have rep points for posting pics)
http://www.pohrani.com/f/v/AQ/2bPLiVcP/slika.jpg